# Can't get my Java class to work

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am supposed to make a class and a tester class that allows a client to enter his name and current amount of money as well as any deposits or withdrawals that he would like to make. There is probably improper code but I am wondering what I am doing wrong with the code. One of the problems is that it says getBalance is an invalid method declaration.

This is the class with the constructors

```
public class BankAccount{
    public String name;
    public double Balance, Withdrawal, Deposit;

    public BankAccount(double bal, String nm){
        name = nm;
        Balance = bal;
    }


    public void setName (String nm){
        name = nm;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name:    " + name + "\n" +
        "New Balance :     " + getBalance;
    }

    public getBalance(){
        return Balance;
    }

    public double Withdrawal(){
        bal = Balance - Withdrawal;
    }

    public double Deposit(){
        bal = Balance + Deposit;
    }
}
```

This is the tester class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccountTester{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        a1 = new BankAccount();

        String name;
        int Balance, Withdrawal, Deposit;

        System.out.println("What is the name of the bank account holder?");
        name = reader.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is your current balance?");
        Balance = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much do you wish to deposit?");
        Deposit = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much do you with to withdraw?");
        Withdrawal = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n" + a1.getName());

    }
}
```

Would you mind telling me what I am doing wrong and explaining it?

Comment: It's standard practice in Java to use capital initial letters for classes and lower case initial letters for variables. This will make your code easier to read for fellow Java developers.

Comment: `a1 = new BankAccount();` Shouldn't this be written as: `BankAccount a1 = new BankAccount();`? I'm not seeing `a1` being declared anywhere else in your `BankAccountTester` class.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves negative reputation. Yes, the solution may be a simple one, but the question was well thought out and the code was concise and easily readable. Compared to 95% of the questions, this one deserves a round of applause.

Comment: @DrewKennedy-Even I upvoted the question for this much of clarity && proper devotion to code. Seriously applaudable!

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `getBalance()` method is missing whereas you're returning a variable of type double. Declare it as :-

```
public double getBalance(){   // add double as the return-type here
    return Balance;
}
```

Also,as mentioned by Drew Kennedy---declare object of BankAccount class by adding BankAccount class along with a1. You haven't mentioned it anywhere...

```
BankAccount a1 = new BankAccount();  // you're missing class name BankAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getBalance()` method needs a return type. Change the declaration to `public double getBalance()`. As a side note, Java convention says not to capitalize the first letter of a variable name. Following convention makes your code easier to read by others which will result in more and better responses.

Answer (score 0):

The getBalance() method doesn't have a return type and yet you asked it to return a value. Also try to follow the Java naming conventions, a variable name should not start with a capital letter.